# DAX Moving Average Reconciliation

Tags: excel, dax

Following tutorials I have a dax formula that calculates a 12 month moving average. However it seems slightly off from what users would be expecting.

```
12 Month Moving Average:=AVERAGEX (
      FILTER (
           ALL (dim_Calendar ),
          dim_Calendar[Month_from_date_iso] > ( NEXTDAY ( SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( LASTDATE (dim_Calendar[Date_iso] ) ) ) ) && /* t1 */
          dim_Calendar[Month_from_date_iso] <= MAX (dim_Calendar[Date_iso] )  /* t2 */
   ),[Total Month Sales])
```

Edit: adding Total Month Sales

```
Total Month Sales:=CALCULATE (
  SUM([Sales Gross]),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( dim_Calendar),
       dim_Calendar[Month_from_date_iso] = MAX (dim_Calendar[Month_from_date_iso] )
    )
)
```

I would have expected Column F to match Column E.
[image]

Am I misunderstanding how AVERAGEX works or is this a rookie error?

Edit2: progress update. Demonstrating how the proposed solution calculates the overall average, not last 12 months. 
[image]

Comment: What is the formula for [Total Month Sales] ?

Comment: @DAX0110 I've edited the question to add [Total Month Sales]. Thanks for taking the time to look over this

Comment: What's Month_from_date_iso vs Date_iso?  In your formula they seem to be compared directly to each other.

Comment: @DAX0110 [Date_iso] is a date field formatted "DD/MM/YY" and [Month_from_date_iso] is the first date of the [Date_iso] month eg. if [Date_iso] = 20/07/2014 then [Month_from_date_iso] = 01/07/2014 for that row